# pdf with extrafont creates overlapping text

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, ggplot2, knitr

I'm trying to use the Arial typeface in my pdfs, but when I follow the instructions in the extrafont help file, the text at each point is written over each other:

```
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)

my_pdf <- function(file, width, height){
  loadfonts()
  pdf(file = file, width = width, height = height,
      family = "Arial")
} 

my_pdf("ArialTester.pdf")
qplot(1:10, 1:10, "point") + ggtitle(paste0(LETTERS,letters, collapse=""))
dev.off()
```

I get the below in the pdf. Note that the title is meant to be the alphabet.

The context of this question is knitr, so I need a device function that I can set as a chunk option (i.e. `dev = 'my_pdf'`)

[image]

What have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `embed_fonts()`.

```
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)

my_pdf <- function(file, width, height){
  loadfonts()
  pdf(file = file, width = width, height = height,
      family = "Arial")
}

my_pdf("ArialTester.pdf")
g <- qplot(1:10, 1:10, "point") + ggtitle(paste0(LETTERS,letters, collapse="")) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial"))
plot(g)
dev.off()
embed_fonts("ArialTester.pdf")
```

Comment: I need a `my_pdf` type function as I want this to be able to handle output in `knitr`.

Comment: Hugh, I edited my answer to keep the function. I think all you needed to do was add `embed_fonts()` step.